# Echoing admin menu child items

Tags: 7, routes

When you click 'Structure' in Drupal admin the page displayed is a print of the child items of the 'Structure' menu item.

I imagine this behaviour is relatively simple to achieve? I have a custom menu item using hook_menu but what do I need to do in page_callback in order to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items['admin/sponsorship'] = array(

    'title' => 'Sponsorship',
    'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
    'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
);
```

Seems to have done the trick.